# Right gravity of textview in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, layout-gravity

I want to display data of emi calculation in listview, i am displaying it but the problem is it's gravity is not same for every textview in row, i mean i set gravity right for all but it's not looking in linear as in screenshot [image]

I want every textview in right aligned and should be liner column vise.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emi_calc_row_tv_year"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Year"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emi_calc_row_tv_principal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Principal"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_gravity="right" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emi_calc_row_tv_interest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Interest"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emi_calc_row_tv_total"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Total\n(A+B)"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emi_calc_row_tv_balance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Balance"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: then try to set `android:gravity ="right'` instead of `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K : I already tried it but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:gravity="right"` instead of  `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`.

And change the width from `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

This is an example from your code, i've tested it and it works.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/emi_calc_row_tv_year"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Year"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="right" />
```

Comment: it works when textview length is same but if its differs then the problem is as like the screenshot which i have attched.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you are confuse the define of two attribute `android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity`.

- `android:gravity` sets the gravity of the content of the View its used
  on.
- `android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the View or Layout in
  its parent.

So, you need change each TextView to

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emi_calc_row_tv_balance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Balance"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="right"  />
```